# How is it possible to mask a certain window or region in a Video

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have mp4 video which has around 50000 frames of size 1920x720. I have to remove a specific area in the video (all frames). Can you suggest a method in MATLAB?

Comment: think of how to apply a mask to each image and then read every frame of video, treat as an image and apply the same method. Look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/specifying-a-region-of-interest-roi.html#bq3146_) page for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the video file frame-by-frame, then it is a simple matter of matrix-indexing to remove a specific area (make it black as you said):

```
for i=1:numFrames
    % read next frame
    frame = <.. get i-th frame..>;

    % black out region
    frame(100:200, 300:350) = 0;
end
```

If the frames are RBG, just adjust indexing appropriately: `frame(a:b,c:d,:)=0`

Answer (score 1):

Specify a ROI(Region of Interest) for each individual frame of the video, where the ROI is the specific area that you wanted to remove. Quite simple. Hope my advice helped. If u are still not sure, comment on this answer, I will add in more hints.

Comment: I have the image 1920*1080. I want to select roi of size 430*270 in some coordinate of the image and make that black.

What will be syntax of ROI

Comment: There is an example there. Look under "Creating an ROI Without an Associated Image". It's pretty simple. (:

Comment: Another more straight forward and simpler method can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/roiposition.html. If u do need an example, let me know again, I will edit my answer to show u. After specifying the ROI, u just need to mask set the pixels in the ROI specified by setting it to zero as Amro mentioned(: